# Significance of lizard falls on our Human Body

Tags: astrology, superstitions

One of the major things that Lizard falls on our part of human body and its predict our destiny?

There is any hopeful source said as truth like in Puranas or in Panjangams?

Comment: Your question is about Superstition , Such superstitions are not part of Scriptures Of Hinduism. And nowhere mentioned so. Such a beliefs/superstitions are part of culture. And Hold by common people. Hinduism never have advocated such things. Apart from that it was belief of bygone days. Most of such misbeliefs won't exists today.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar No. This may not be a superstition. Gouli Sastra deals specially with lizards. There are carved lizards in Kanchipuram Varadaraja Temple. Popular belief is that those who touch those lizards will never get affected when lizard falls.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: Superstitious describes a belief in chance or magic. If you're superstitious, you may avoid walking under ladders, spilling salt, or passing black cats — all because you think they will bring you bad luck. Plenty of people don't think of themselves as superstitious, yet they may do things like knock on wood or refuse to open an umbrella indoors. Or they believe their team will win if they wear their lucky socks. These actions are all superstitious, demonstrating a belief based on magic or luck rather than on reason.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Agni Purana describes omens in particular. Actually, in those days seers comprehended all esoteric and subtle elements of nature and expounded some omens. But time has changed some of them still applies while some don't apply now. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11584/3500). You must consider subtle elements too for better understanding.

Comment: @The Destroyer - I agree , but in any sense the question dose not help Hinduism. Rather it is indicative towards giving  message that Hinduism is about superstitions. No such a thing is mentioned in main Scriptures (exception folkstories) which are not main Scriptures.The questioner says it is major thing. Rather Hinduism is great scientific believe system from starting.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yeah. Santana Dharma is based on Science but Science of both Physical and Spiritual worlds or science of subtle world. If we remove Subtle science then it looks like superstition and sometimes meaningless. Puranas are definitely main scriptures. Superstition is something which doesn't have reason or logic. But if we don't apply laws of Subtle Science, how can we say decide something as superstition? Let me see if Agni Purana mentions about lizards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if Puranas say such. But Gauli Sastra mentions the different omens or sakunas in detail. Gauli Sastra is prominent Sakuna system published with Panchangams or Astrology books in Andhra Pradesh, Karnataka and Tamilnadu.

Shri Ragavendra Rao (M.A in Astrology) from Tirupati Sri Venkteswara University translated the Telugu Manuscripts to English and published them in [Saptarishi](http://www.saptarishisastrology.com/filedownload.php?v=7&a=y&b=n&f=56-GauliPatnamGavuliPalkuLakshanam.pdf) Astrology Magazine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see the preserved Telugu Manuscripts of Gauli Sastra in above attached PDF.

Comment: It is different for male and female. But you have posted only one version.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes. English version is limited. I couldn't get complete one.

Comment: haha ..how can the lizard fall on one's tongue?..BTw nice find ..

Comment: @Rickross Haha. Yeah. I don't know how they found it, but this Sakuna System is quite famous in South India.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Bengalis also believe in such omens..For ex, they believe if u utter something and at the same time a lizard makes the "tik tik tik" sound then what u said will come true..I think [Khana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khana_(poet))  made these omens popular in Bengal..

Comment: @Rickross Yes this is common belief across India. A question is also asked [When a lizard makes noise whatever we think may happen --Is it a myth or true?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16047/3500)

Comment: Ok ..but i don't think we can have scripture based answer for that question..but i may be wrong too..

Comment: I didn't know that when lizards fall on us, they have significance. Can we only know this because of karma? I think this would show that we gave someone a sign of something very relevant but in a very subtle manner in a past life. This shows how complex system of Karma is.

Answer (score 2):

Its has deep meaning. Its not limited to just body, i mean if lizard falls on your right hand, mouth, toes, everything has different meaning.

Also, different meaning for different gender. For example if lizard falls on lower lip of men, it will be financial loss for him, while if lizard falls on lower lip of women, it will bring positive results for her. Likewise, it has different meaning for all other body parts as well.  Here is detail meaning for both men and women for their different body parts, published in [Astrolaabh](https://astrolaabh.in/article/lizard-falling-body-parts/), do check out below.

[image]
[image]
Hope this will help you to understand things better about lizard Astrology.

Comment: Welcome although you have provided source link in your answer , it looks like you are the owner of the site. Site advertisement and promotion  is not encouraged here. So pls. do try to add sources from scriptures like purana , itihasa etc. if possible.

Comment: I will take care from the future, sir. Thank you!