# When a lizard makes noise whatever we think may happen --Is it a myth or true?

Tags: scripture, puranas, belief, superstitions

Generally when we are in house thinking some good things or bad things, if a lizard makes noise, there is a saying that whatever we thought at that time will happen. Good things or bad things may happen. It is also said we have to listen  how many times the lizard made noise? If it made 3 times there will be a result  for that. If it is 4 the result will vary. Similarly increase the counts.

Is it a myth or true? Anywhere in Hindu scriptures this has been mentioned?

Comment: It is true, because your thought is your life. You think about your wish often and the lizards acknowledge them, which brings hope...Which may comes true but it happened because of your thought and wish, not because of lizard...! Lizards astrology is been added to our practice through our life style and it is not mentioned in any of our scriptures like in Vedas or in shivapuran...