# Is breaking of glass and fire going off from lamps a bad omen?

Tags: belief, omens

We often see in Movies and Television series that shows few incidents in which something bad/negative happens if the glass breaks or fire goes off from the lamps which are lightened in temples or pooja room. And that is considered as apshagun/bad omen.

- Is it true or superstitious?
- Is there any reference from scripture?

Comment: What is "Asphagun"? Is Aspagun, *Apasakunam* or bad omen?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Exactly, Apasakunam.

Comment: [Agni Purana Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12912/6/Chapter4_547-617p.pdf) (Ch:229-233) describes some omens and scientifically they are outcomes of changes in Physical and Subtle worlds. For example, see [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11584/3500). I'm not sure about belief of breaking of glass.

Comment: @TheDestroyer that's about the animals and time. I'm asking about the Glass and Lamp.

Comment: Yes. I think either they were introduced later by analyzing esoteric and subtle phenomenon of nature or just superstitions. Agni Purana doesn't mention about Glass or lamps. BTW, Can you edit your title as "Is Breaking of glass a bod omen?" or something similar to it for higher readability.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it true or superstitious?

Calling those things apshagun has no connection with superstitions nor they are just 'religious' things. In previous days, we had no sources of power like we have today. People used to depend on sunlight in day and candle or 'diya' in night. So diya bujhna i.e. Fire going off used to be really bad thing  as they end up in darkness. that's why it is considered as 'not good' (Apshagun i.e. Which does not bring Shagun) thing, but unfortunately even in this era we carried that education as it is without even thinking cause behind it.

Similar thing you can say about breaking of glass. We have plain marble floors today at our home. But in previous time (few centuries, not too much previous as glass was not even invented that early), they didn't have such cleanable floors. So breaking glass on that rough muddy floor and then picking all the tiny pieces up without vacuum cleaner can be really tiring (plus no guarantee of cleaning it 100%). That's why it is also considered as 'not good thing' again. There is no such thing as apshagun as our Hindu religion heavily based on science and causes not just religious beliefs.

- Is there any reference from scripture?

Well I don't exactly know the answer of that question as there is not just one holy book in Hindu religion and I have not read all of them. But I can tell you this definitely that There will not be anything in any holy book telling about superstitions without giving the "cause" behind it. you just have to think about it and research if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources from scriptures and speculative theories are not encouraged on this site.

Comment: Also practically, reason behind the "diya bujhna" are air, less oil and incorrect arrangement of Wick. Without those lamp will definitely glow. And for glass, same incorrect arrangement applies. If it is mentioned in any book then we may consider, if not it is imaginary for sure.